# You just realized I am doomed

Tags: riddle, story, video-games

> You just found a game despite the World War III,
> which was a game by some computer experts before the war.
>
> There went a six-limbed, not an insect.
> I was not blind, I sincerely swear.
> I ate something healthy, yet not nutritious.
> Maybe I was hallucinating, by that cosmic light.
> I won't eat a pudding, because it's dangerous to eat.
> I couldn't know what just hit me on the back.
>
> You use your index finger while not taking attention,
> then you just realized that I am doomed.

What do **you** want after all of this?

Subtle Hint:

> There was a close relative of humans,
>  and another six-limbed.
>  There was the first swindler,
>  and yet another six-limbed!

Moderate Hint:

> This game was released in 1987.

Decisive Hint:

> @

Decisive Hint 2:

> The game asks what you want.

Comment: I want *peace*.

Comment: I've no idea what the six-limbed reference is to (a compass maybe?) but this sounds a lot like (rot13)argunpx to me

Comment: @postmortes Correct. Now think about six-limbed monsters.

Comment: I think this needs a new hint to give some direction to what the actual question is. See my partial answer, where I understand the context perfectly well but don't know what is being asked.

Comment: @Josh Second decisive hint is given.

Comment: Thank you. I've added another guess to my answer.

Comment: I have done a major update to my answer now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Completely re-edited answer**

I think I figured it out, after realizing one of my earlier assumptions was not what you wanted.

The game is confirmed to be:

> Nethack

The answer is:

> What I want is to have my possessions identified.

And the reason is:

There went a six-limbed, not an insect.

> If you count wings as a type of limb, then this is a **Dragon**. Dragons are represented by **D**. My original assumption here was "Centaur", but that has to be wrong.

I was not blind, I sincerely swear.

> **yellow light** is represented by **y**. They explode and blind you.

I ate something healthy, yet not nutritious.

> Eating a **Wraith** (**W**) corpse has zero nutrition but usually gives you a level.

Maybe I was hallucinating, by that cosmic light.

> The other **y**, **black light**. It explodes and makes you hallucinate.

I won't eat a pudding, because it's dangerous to eat.

> Puddings are **P**

I couldn't know what just hit me on the back.

> The capital letter **I** shows up when a monster's position is known but it is invisible.

All of this together makes:

> DyWyPI : "Do you want your possessions identified?" , the first question you are asked when you die.

Comment: That game is related, but as I've clarified, the game is rot13(ArgUnpx).

Comment: I'm very familiar with that game. Many ascensions under my belt. But I still don't know what the actual question is in the riddle.
(rot13)Znlor rnpu yvar vf n uvag gbjneq gur yrggre gung ercerfragf n zbafgre, naq vg fcryyf bhg n jbeq? Va juvpu pnfr, P sbe Pragnhe (fvk-yrttrq zbafgre). l sbe "gung pbfzvp yvtug". C sbe Chqqvat. Gelvat gb svther bhg gur erfg bs gur uvagf.

Comment: Yes, that's the answer. Think about how monsters are displayed.

Comment: I think I've got what you are going for. Major re-edit of my answer incoming...